# Cant read Enum definition on Typescript Build

Tags: typescript, npm, definitelytyped

I have a typescript package in npm who stores all definitions to my projects:

`index.d.ts`

```
export declare namespace OfferCraft {
    enum Country {
        es,
        it,
        fr,
        uk,
        de
    }

    enum Brand {
        amazon,
        eci,
        ldld,
        nvidia
    }

    interface Log {
        msg: string
        telegram?: boolean
        title?: string
        color?: string
    }

    interface Product {
        sku: string;
        brand: Brand;
        country: Country;
        url: string;
        name: string;
        image: string;
        prime: boolean;
        price?: number;
        reacoprice?: number;
        stock?: number;
    }
}
```

In my others project i install my npm package and vscode identify types well and i dont have any lint errors:

[image]

But when i try to build my project i recieve this error:

[image]

Im very frustated at this point. I try several options without success.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `declare` keyword, and it should work. The `declare` keyword is only used when you want to describe types for javascript that is present at runtime (e.g., globals) but has no type declarations yet. Namespaces which are preceded by a `declare` are purely declarative and won't get transpiled into any runtime code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEAUCcHsBMFcDGBTAzqZAPADtSAXUANwENJQB5AMyuUgGFISr8BuAWACgtcDQA7EgFs02Eiko06jZoQDeXUEoz94Q0PWjx%20%20SAE9QCzspMZUAGkWmlAS3yXj10FUgOnoeAGs3T2MitKAL5cXMGcIKAAkujQ-AA2BtiQaMg6znigiNBC2DZxyKD4NiKFetgFqMzI%20HoAdKAActCZcAU26Lok-Ki5%20bDOMOp2tVw8eIR%20iHFkBYIiPeIF1LQMTCwATIYBKmoaWjr6W47WaD7WdmemLpcmXjfKftthgUA)):

```
// Produces export var OfferCraft;
export namespace OfferCraft {
    enum Country {
        es,
        it,
        fr,
        uk,
        de
    }

}
// Is only present for compile time type safety. No code is transpiled from it.
export declare namespace OfferCraft2 {
    enum Country {
        es,
        it,
        fr,
        uk,
        de
    }
}
```